# python, test whether all values in matrix less than numpy.finfo(float).eps

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I want to test whether all the elements of a matrix are equal to zero or not. I have a 3x3 matrix that contains very small but non-zero elements. Something like this:

```
my_matrix = numpy.mat(
[[  1.32439783e-16,  -1.09384837e-16,   5.22327024e-17],
[ -1.47879836e-17,   1.58560316e-17,  -8.18983137e-19],
[  3.40590503e-17,  -1.36768936e-17,   3.33256165e-17]]
)
```

I would normally use:

```
np.array_equal( my_matrix, np.zeros((3,3)) )
```

But this returns `False`. I was under the impression that since the absolute values of all elements inside this matrix are less than `numpy.finfo(float).eps`, where `1.0 + eps = 1.0`, this should return `True`.

Is there a way to test whether all values in a matrix are less than `numpy.finfo(float).eps`?

By the way, `numpy.finfo(float).eps = 2.22044604925e-16`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're comparing two mats of floats, use `np.allclose` instead:

```
In [119]: np.allclose( my_matrix, np.zeros((3,3)) )
Out[119]: True
```

Comment: @JoeDanger glad to help, you can accept my answer if you like it ;)